# Node.Js - Attempting to push req.body to an objects array but running into trouble

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on a library management software project but I'm running into trouble when trying to implement check out functionality. The Angular part of my application passes a put request with the user id in the request and the book in the body. In my NodeJs application the put is supposed to add the book to an array in the user object, but whenever I try this instead of the book being added to the array a new object made up of only one of the books properties is added.

The Node.Js checkout function looks like this:

```
exports.checkOut = (req, res, next) =>{
   Book.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body._id,{
      checkedOutTo: req.params.userid,
      currentlyCheckedOut: true
   }, { new: true });
   User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.userid, {
      $push: {"booksCheckedOut": req.body} 
   }, { new: true })
   .then((user) => {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
      res.json(user);
   }, (err) => next(err))
   .catch((err) => next(err));
}
```

The user model looks like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Book = require("./book.model").schema;

const User = mongoose.model(
   "User",
   new mongoose.Schema({
      username: String,
      email: String,
      password: String,
      booksCheckedOut: [Book]
   })
);
module.exports = User;
```

The book model looks like this

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Book= mongoose.model(
   "Book",
   new mongoose.Schema({
      author: String,
      title: String,
      genre: String,
      currentlyCheckedOut: { type: Boolean, default: false}
   })
);
module.exports = User;
```

The Angular function that sends the request looks like this

```
checkOut(book: any, userid: string){
   let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-type',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT'
   });
   
   return this.http.put(`http://localhost:8080/api/book/update/${userid}`, {book}, {headers})
      .subscribe(
         res => console.log(res),
         err => console.log(err)      
      );
}
```

What is it I'm doing wrong? I don't know if I need to include anything, so let me know if I do

Comment: You have a `module.exports = User;` in your Book model.

Comment: @prasad_ I'm looking over my code and that's actually a typo

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the problem was basically that using req.body didn't return anything because I still had to refer to the book object inside of the body. Replacing req.body with req.body.book fixed everything. Also when using findByIdAndUpdate those id's I'm passing were actually strings that had to be cast to the ObjectId type.